# Click on <div> to focus <input> (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I know how to do this with jquery. But I am stuck with React: How would I focus an input field, whenever the user clicks on a div?

Comment: Why a div? Normally when people want that, a label would make more sense.

Comment: You could use a [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and add a click handler

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to have an `onClick` event on the div and the call the `focus()` function on the input element that you can access by `refs` in react

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div onClick={() => {this.myInp.focus()}}>Focus Input</div>
          <input type="text" ref={(ip) => this.myInp = ip} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In the above snippet `ref={(ip) => this.myInp = ip}` is a callback approach of declaring refs which is recommended by [react-docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: TypeError: this.myInp.focus is not a function

Comment: @ArtemKha, focus needs to be a defined action on the element you are calling it, for example it won't work for a div

Comment: Official React documentation has a better example.
I prefer to use `focusTextInput = () => this.textInput.current.focus();`
instead of `this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);`

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element

Comment: what if i'm mapping in an array that has multiple inputs, how to set onClick to focus the input. PS: the map function returns a `<div>` inside the div an input and button both  has the same id AKA index of array.

Comment: what if i'm mapping in an array that has multiple inputs, how to set onClick to focus the input. PS: the map function returns a `<div>` inside the div an input and button both  has the same id AKA index of array.

Comment: what if i'm mapping in an array that has multiple inputs, how to set onClick to focus the input. PS: the map function returns a `<div>` inside the div an input and button both  has the same id AKA index of array.

Comment: @sasharomanov You would need to have your refs as an array and then onClick target the correct ref element

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri can you give example on how to make ref in an array

Answer (score 3):

Check this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Via `ref` you can anything jquery-like.