# React / Redux - focus input field of Component 1 by click on button in Component 2

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I asked a question on here earlier, but I think I should have been more specific. Say I have two components, which I call from a higher order component:

So my higher order component, containing these components, looks like this (or at least its render method):

```
<div>
  <Navigation />
  <View />
</div>
```

Now, `Navigation />` contains a button. Whenever that button is clicked, I want to set the focus on an input field, which is in `<View />`.

If both things were in the very same component, I learned that I would do something like this:

```
<button onClick={() => {this.myInp.focus()}}>Focus Input</button>
<input type="text" ref={(ip) => this.myInp = ip} />
```

I am using Redux by the way, if this should make a difference.

Comment: mention that in your previous ques, one who answered that ques will provide you the solution for this also, mention this in the accepted answer @Shubham will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43805395/5185595

Comment: It's strictly speaking a different question though, i feel bad changing my question now and then all the people who have answered that original question are off with their answers. I also already selected an answer which is working perfectly, so I'd rather keep things clean.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are descendants of the same element you can use a `state` element and function to change that `state` element in the parent `div` and pass down as `props` to `View` and `Navigation`.

```
constructor(){

   super()

   this.state = {
    inputFocus:false;
   }

   this.setInputFocus = this.setInputFocus.bind(this)

}

setInputFocus(value){
   this.setState({inputFocus:false});
}
```

Then in the `render` method of the div just pass them down as `props`

```
<div>
  <Navigation setInputFocus={this.setInputFocus}/>
  <View inputFocus={this.state.inputFocus}/>
</div>
```

In the `Navigation`

```
<button onClick={() => {this.props.setInputFocus(true)}}>Focus Input</button>
```

and in the `View`

```
<input type="text"  ref={(ip) => this.myInp = ip}/>
```

and have this in the `componentWillReceiveProps` which detects when `props` change and runs actions then.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

    if(nextProps.inputFocus)
        this.myInp.focus()

}
```

So when the `inputFocus` changes in the parent it will fire the `componentWillReceiveProps` in the `View` element and `focus` the `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the refs, this problems also involves child to parent and parent to child interaction.

So what I am doing in the below snippet is form the Navigation component, I have to call the parent component since a component can't directly have access to its siblings. From the parent you can get access to the child component through refs and in turn you can also access the refs which are defined in the child component

See the snippet below

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  focusInput = () => {
      this.myView.myInput.focus()
  }
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
         <Navigation focusInput={this.focusInput}/>
          <View ref={(view) => {this.myView = view}}/>
       </div>
    )
  }
}


class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={() => this.props.focusInput()}>Focus</button>
    ) 
  }
}
class View extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <input type="text" ref={(ip) => this.myInput = ip}/>
    ) 
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In case you have multiple buttons in navigation thorugh which you want to focus multiple different inputs, you can do so in the following manner

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  focusInput = (ip) => {
      this.myView[ip].focus()
  }
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
         <Navigation focusInput={(val) => this.focusInput(val)}/>
          <View ref={(view) => {this.myView = view}}/>
       </div>
    )
  }
}


class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.focusInput("myInput1")}>Focus1</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.focusInput("myInput2")}>Focus2</button>
        </div>
    ) 
  }
}
class View extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" ref={(ip) => this.myInput1 = ip}/>
          <input type="text" ref={(ip) => this.myInput2 = ip}/>
        </div>
    ) 
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This is not very good solution: now App needs to know about references in View component. It's better to avoid such coupling.